# запрос через сводную таблицу QB symfony2

Tags: php, sql, symfony2, doctrine2

Здравствуйте. Не могу сделать фильтр. Вот что имеется:

Order entity с полем product

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * One Order has Many OrderProduct.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProduct", mappedBy="order")
 */
private $product;

/**
 * CatalogOrder constructor.
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->product = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

OrderProduct entity с полями product, order и number (данная сущность нужна для хранения количества заказанных продуктов)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CatalogOrder", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $order;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="order")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="integer")
 */
private $number;
```

Product entity с полем order

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProduct", mappedBy="product")
 */
private $order;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->order = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Хочу на фронтенде искать по названию товара в заказах, т.е. вводим "пив" и выводит все заказы с продуктом "пиво".

Попытка не верна:

```
$qb->join('o.product', 'p')
    ->where('p.product.name LIKE :name')
    ->setParameter('name', '%'.$filters['productName'].'%');
```

Comment: Судя по сущностям у Вас нет name в таблице product

Comment: Можете полный запрос вывести?

Comment: Вопрос решился, нужно было просто делать 2 join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ на мой вопрос, так как у меня есть промежуточная таблица нужно делать такой запрос:

```
$qb->join('o.product', 'op')
    ->join('op.product', 'p')
    ->where('p.name LIKE :name')
    ->setParameter('name', '%'.$filters['productName'].'%')
;
```

Всем спасибо